# Mathematica quits calculation automatically

Tags: manipulate

I have this little program that is adopted from a Wolfram demonstrations project (link here: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PercolationOnASquareGrid/).

I want to see what happen if I increase the matrix size to 1000 or even above but Mathematica quits me. If I made the change inside Manipulate, it just showed "Manipulate Aborted". If it is without Manipulate, it quits the Kernel.

I don't if it there is a glitch in my version (9.00) or simply because the limit of Mathematica...

Thanks a lot for your time!!

```
h = 1000;
p = 0.59;

Block[{a, $RecursionLimit = 25000, w = h}, 
 per[{i_, j_}] := 
  If[1 <= i <= w && 1 <= j <= h && a[[i, j]] == 1, a[[i, j]] = 2;
   per[{i, j} + #] & /@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}}];
 SeedRandom[2424];
 a = Map[Boole[# < p] &, RandomReal[{0, 1}, {w, h}], {2}];
 a[[All, 1]] = a[[All, h]] = 1; Do[per[{i, 1}]; per[{i, h}], {i, w}];
 ArrayPlot[Transpose[a], ImageSize -> 1000, Mesh -> True, 
  ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Darker[Blue], 2 -> Red}]]
```

Another piece that doesn't work:

```
L = 1000;
p1 = 0.6;
seed = 2000;

perColation[{i_, j_}] :=

  If[1 <= i <= L && 1 <= j <= L && a[[i, j]] == 1,
   a[[i, j]] = 2;
   perColation[{i + 1, j}];
   perColation[{i - 1, j}];
   perColation[{i, j + 1}];
   perColation[{i, j - 1}];
   ];

SeedRandom[seed];

Block[{a, $RecursionLimit = Infinity},
 a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {L, L}];
 For[j = 1, j <= L, j++,
  For[i = 1, i <= L, i++,
   If[a[[i, j]] < p1,
    a[[i, j]] = 1,
    a[[i, j]] = 0
    ]]];

 a[[IntegerPart[L/2], IntegerPart[L/2]]] = 1;
 perColation[{IntegerPart[L/2], IntegerPart[L/2]}];
 ArrayPlot[Transpose[a], ImageSize -> 1000, 
  ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> White, 2 -> Red}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the `Mesh->True` Removing it works:

```
h = 1000;
p = 0.59;

Block[{a, $RecursionLimit = 25000, w = h},
 per[{i_, j_}] := If[1 <= i <= w && 1 <= j <= h && a[[i, j]] == 1,
   a[[i, j]] = 2;
   per[{i, j} + #] & /@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}}
   ];

 SeedRandom[2424];

 a = Map[Boole[# < p] &, RandomReal[{0, 1}, {w, h}], {2}];

 a[[All, 1]] = a[[All, h]] = 1; Do[per[{i, 1}]; per[{i, h}], {i, w}];

 ArrayPlot[Transpose[a], ImageSize -> 1000, 
    ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Darker[Blue], 2 -> Red}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From `ref/Mesh` it says

`For ArrayPlot, Mesh->True draws mesh divisions between every cell.`

And it must be that with the larger size, it failed to do this. The same problem shows up with `Mesh->All`.

You can either remove this options, or specify a smaller mesh value using `Mesh->n`.

btw, on V 9.01, with `Mesh->True` I do not get crash, just a gray box is displayed. No messages of any error or warning on the console. Windows 7, 16 GB RAM

Comment: Thanks a lot Nasser. Removing "Mesh" seems working. But I have another piece that crash again and doesn't include Mesh. I added the code into my original question. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3513537 no crash here with the new piece of code you posted. it works. Screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2j0V0.png)  using V 9.01 on windows 7, 64 bit

Comment: I see. It must be the memory limit. I use a mac 2.4GHz intel i5 and 8G memory. I will find another computer to run it and see what happen. Thanks!